How to make the following div center in CSS by centering these content and how the contents of the following should be placed together?
I'm trying to center the content with this text and image inside a div element horizontally and vertically. I've defined a width for the div, but the content remains aligned to the left/right edge by default and it should be paired or sticked with the image. How can I achieve a centered layout with placing each content closer using CSS same when it comes to vice versa? Here is the attached image:
Problem:

Solution:

Here is what I try and I was expecting that it will stick the contents to each other, same goes when it comes to vice versa:


.joron_description {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.joron_description img {
    height: 229px;
    width: 210px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.joron_description .joron-text {
    background-color: rgb(7, 15, 43, 0.8);
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
<div class="joron_description">
  <img src="/assets/about_img/joron-about_img.png" alt="Joron's Image">
  <div class="joron-text">
    <p>
      Joaquin Aaron P. Recio | The Lead Programmer of Hug Haven.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>



I hope they are solutions so far in this problems, replies in this question is much appreciated! :)

In .joron_description, change justify-content: space-between; to justify-content: center;.
.joron_description {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%; 
}

You can see it here.

Modify HTML. Just add Inner div.
<div class="joron_description">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <img src="/assets/about_img/joron-about_img.png" alt="Joron's Image">
    <div class="joron-text">
      <p>
        Joaquin Aaron P. Recio | The Lead Programmer of Hug Haven.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


Using justify-content: center will align the items to the center of their container, in your case, joron_description. Meanwhile, justify-content: space-between will display them spaced out.
For further info, refer to this site
